# Prove that A is a subset of B. A= {p odd prime...}

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

A={p odd prime | p= $a^2 + b^2$ for some a,b ∈ Z}

B={p odd prime | p= $4k+1$ for some k ∈ Z}

When I plug in my cases ($a= 4l, 4l+1, 4l+2, 4l+3$) I get stuck with the $b^2$. How do I take out a 4 if b cannot be divided by 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $p \in A$. We want to show that $p \in B$. We know that there exists $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p = a^2+b^2$. If $a$ and $b$ are both odd or both even, then $a^2+b^2$ is even which contradicts the assumption that $p$ is an **odd** prime. So one of them, say $a$, is odd and the other one is even. We can thus write $a = 2k+1$ and $b=2m$ for some $k,m \in \mathbb{Z}$. We have
$$a^2+b^2 = (2k+1)^2+(2m)^2 = 4k^2+4k+1+4m^2 = 4(k^2+k+m^2)+1 = p$$
so $p = 4n+1$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. This proves that $A\subset B$.

I hope this gives some clarification.

Remark: Actually, one has $A = B$ but the other inclusion is a little bit harder to show: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares

Comment: This makes so much sense! Would this be the only thing i have to prove?

Comment: Yes. $A\subset B$ is equivalent to saying that $x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the only cases in which $a^2+b^2$ is odd:

- $[a\equiv0\pmod4]\wedge[b\equiv1\pmod4]\implies[a^2+b^2\equiv0^2+1^2\equiv 1\equiv1\pmod4]$
- $[a\equiv0\pmod4]\wedge[b\equiv3\pmod4]\implies[a^2+b^2\equiv0^2+3^2\equiv 9\equiv1\pmod4]$
- $[a\equiv1\pmod4]\wedge[b\equiv0\pmod4]\implies[a^2+b^2\equiv1^2+0^2\equiv 1\equiv1\pmod4]$
- $[a\equiv1\pmod4]\wedge[b\equiv2\pmod4]\implies[a^2+b^2\equiv1^2+2^2\equiv 5\equiv1\pmod4]$
- $[a\equiv2\pmod4]\wedge[b\equiv1\pmod4]\implies[a^2+b^2\equiv2^2+1^2\equiv 5\equiv1\pmod4]$
- $[a\equiv2\pmod4]\wedge[b\equiv3\pmod4]\implies[a^2+b^2\equiv2^2+3^2\equiv13\equiv1\pmod4]$
- $[a\equiv3\pmod4]\wedge[b\equiv0\pmod4]\implies[a^2+b^2\equiv3^2+0^2\equiv 9\equiv1\pmod4]$
- $[a\equiv3\pmod4]\wedge[b\equiv2\pmod4]\implies[a^2+b^2\equiv3^2+2^2\equiv13\equiv1\pmod4]$